# Environmental variables not accessible in Dataflow workers

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

have a Python application which is using Apache beam and Dataflow as runner. The application uses a non-public Python package 'uplight-telemetry' which is configured using 'extra_packages' while creating pipeline_options object. This package expects an environmental variable named 'OTEL_SERVICE_NAME' and since this variable is not present in the Dataflow worker, it is resulting in an error during application startup.

I am passing this variable using custom pipeline options. Code to create pipeline options is as follows-

```
pipeline_options = ProcessBillRequests.CustomOptions(
    project=gcp_project_id,
    region="us-east1",
    job_name=job_name,
    temp_location=f'gs://{TAS_GCS_BUCKET_NAME_PREFIX}{os.getenv("UP_PLATFORM_ENV")}/temp',
    staging_location=f'gs://{TAS_GCS_BUCKET_NAME_PREFIX}{os.getenv("UP_PLATFORM_ENV")}/staging',
    runner='DataflowRunner',
    save_main_session=True,
    service_account_email= service_account,
    subnetwork=os.environ.get(SUBNETWORK_URL),
    extra_packages=[uplight_telemetry_tar_file_path],
    setup_file=setup_file_path,
    OTEL_SERVICE_NAME=otel_service_name,
    OTEL_RESOURCE_ATTRIBUTES=otel_resource_attributes
    # Set values for additional custom variables as needed
```

And the code that executes the pipeline is as follows-

```
result = (
        pipeline
        | "ReadPendingRecordsFromDB" >> read_from_db
        | "Parse input PCollection" >> beam.Map(ProcessBillRequests.parse_bill_data_requests)        
        | "Fetch bills " >> beam.ParDo(ProcessBillRequests.FetchBillInformation())
)
pipeline.run().wait_until_finish()
```

Is there a way I can set the environmental variables in custom options available in the worker?

Answer (score 0):

Why use environment variables in the first place? I am using `argparse` if I need to tell Dataflow some variables during the pipeline start.

Just add the respective arguments to your `main.py`, pass the parameters to your pipeline and access them wherever you need it in the code.
Instead of writing a MWE, allow me to simply reference the official beam git repo (see [here](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/windowed_wordcount.py#L59)). There you might find many other examples.

Comment: As I mentioned, it's a library I am using that's expecting environmental variables. It's not in my application. We don't have an option to make changes in this library as it is being used by a lot of teams

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I was mainly looking at the code and there it was only some paths and the subnetwork - both I pass via argparse.
Since you are using a 3rd party library, I am guessing that it is used within a `DoFn`? Have you tried moving the setting of your env variable to the `setup()` (see [here](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/transforms/python/elementwise/pardo/#example-3-pardo-with-dofn-methods)) method and then importing your 3rd party library also in `setup()`?

Comment: The link does not mention how we can import a non-public dependency in setup() method? Do you have any example where this might have been done?